# Can we define a “directional derivative” at saddle points?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, maxima-minima

Clearly, the standard definition $D_{v}(f):= \nabla f\cdot v$ tells us nothing when $\nabla f = 0$.  In such a case, what other generally applicable methods tell us whether the function increases, decreases, or is level in a direction?

Comment: We can define it but it might be 0.

Comment: Exactly at a saddle point, the instantaneous rate of change is zero in every direction. If you want to look at how the derivative is changing as you get away from the saddle point, I would expect you would want to either look at a different point near the saddle point or look at the second derivatives.

Comment: This isn't quite what you're asking, but if you look at the curvatures of curves through the point (a second-order concept) you can get this type of information. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature has some OK motivation for the concept. Look at in particular the 'principal curvatures.'

Comment: @leslie townes So far, your response is the most helpful.  I am looking for an analogue of the higher derivative test, which allows one to classify behaviour even where the derivative is zero.

Comment: If $f$ is sufficiently differentiable near $x$, and $v$ is a non-zero vector, expand the one-variable function $g(t) = f(x + tv)$ in a Taylor approximation until you find a non-constant term $a_nt^n$. If $n$ is even, then $f$ has a local extremum along this line: A minimum if $a > 0$ and a maximum if $a < 0$. If $n$ is odd, $x$ is not a local extremum along this line. For direction-independent information, Taylor-expand $f$ itself; the sum of the non-constant terms of lowest degree determines the behavior (local minimum/maximum or neither). Is that the type of test you're seeking?

Comment: The discriminant is used as a form of the second derivative test, if that is what you are after.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yeah, getting there.  I am interested in an algorithm for finding which $v$ behave in which ways.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Could you please elaborate?  The discriminant of what?

Comment: To find extrema of a surface, we set $\partial f / \partial x = f_x $ = 0 and likewise for $y$.  To identify whether the extremum is a min, max, or saddle, we compute $D = f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2$.